# Email check in DB with Jquery and PHP using blur function

Tags: jquery

Check if email already exists in DB using jQuery blur function.

It is working but not fully, code is only allowing me to do a check one time.

**Example:** I enter "test@123.com" code does response to me `Email already used`, but when I go back and enter another email, it does not prompt a message.

How to make the code working on every entry we make for an email check. Kindly help

I did try to search a solution online but did not find a possible answer

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        <span id="email-check"></span>
----------------------------------------------------
This is jquery code I created 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#email").blur(function(){
        var email = $("#email").val();
        //alert("Working");
        $.ajax({
            url:"check_email.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{email:email},
            success:function(data){
                if (data !== '0') {
                    $("#email-check").fadeOut(3000).html('<span class="text-danger">Email already exists in database</span>');
                    $("#register_btn").attr("disabled", true);
                    exit();
                }
                else {
                    $("#email-check").fadeOut(3000).html('<span class="text-success">Email Availaible</span>');
                    $("#register_btn").attr("disabled", false);
                    exit();
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

**This is PHP code:**

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "user");

    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $email = $_POST['email'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM newuser where email='$email'";

        $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        echo mysqli_num_rows($res);
    }

?>
```

Comment: Insetd of blur use change event  Please refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp)

Comment: Also beware of SQL injection attacks (https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Tried updating to change event but stil same, no success